# Need to get all ID's in an Excel Cell row with VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Can anyone help me with the following:

I need to get all ID value's into a excel file with VBA into Cell D1. 
I getting al the TD values already but the ID's are not working.

```
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate ("http://www.")

End With

While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend ' Wait for page load

'Clearing any unnecessary or old data in Sheet1
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B1000").ClearContents

Set TR_Elements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
RowNumb = 2
ColumnNumb = 1
'Tables usually consists of TR (Table Rows), and -
'TD (Table Data)
For Each TR In TR_Elements
    Set TD_Elements = TR.getElementsByTagName("td")
    ColumnNumb = 1
    For Each TD In TD_Elements
        ActiveSheet.Cells(RowNumb, ColumnNumb).Value = TD.innerText
        ColumnNumb = ColumnNumb + 1
    Next
    RowNumb = RowNumb + 1
Next


Set ID_Elements = IE.Document.getElementById("itemnummer")

 r = 0
 For Each ID_ELement In ID_Elements
 Sheets(Sheet1).Range("D1").Offset(r, 1).Value = ID_ELement.Value
    r = r + 1
    Next
```

Here is de HTML code from the website:

```
<li id="product">
    <div id="product">
            <div id="image" align="center"><a href="/product/Olieverf/CH111.html">

        <img src="/shop/thumb/CH111.jpg" border="0" />
        </a></div>

        <div id="titel_text"><a href="/product/Olieverf/CH111.html">Olieverfschilderij + Lijst 100x100cm<br>            </a></div>
        <div id="itemnummer">CH111</div>
        <div id="afmetingen"><table><tr><td>100 x 100 x 4</td><td>Voorraad: 22</td></tr></table><br>
        </div>

        </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you want the DIV id? maybe try`td.parent.id` ?

Comment: I Need the information from <div id="itemnummer">CH111</div>

Comment: So the CH111 text in this case

Comment: try `ID_ELement.innertext` `ID_ELement.innerhtml`  I would look at approaching from the `li` object and its `children` of the id's etc.  Not sure if you have from the op.  So apologies if you have.

Comment: Still nothing into Excel

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection, so you can access its innerText property directly without requiring a loop.  Kind of surprised your code does error on that section ...  Also: `Sheets(Sheet1)` should be `Sheets("Sheet1") `

Comment: Use getElementsByTagName("div") then iterate that.  Look at the locals window and debug window.  Also, if you haven't use the MSHTML and Internet Conrols library objects.

Comment: Thanks for the support so far guys. There are almost 700 item numbers on that page. I need to get them all

Comment: I think you can use query selector tags, so "all divs with id product number"  using `document.querySelectorAll(` and a selector of this type https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp   perhaps `div#itemnumber`

Comment: Thanks Nathan this works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try iterating the collection from

`document.querySelectorAll("div#itemnumber")`